# Is there anyway to pull the current url inside a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, parameters

I'm doing some serious hacking. And at a certain point in my row of methods, all my params are lost, and there's no way for me to differentiate between two objects innapropriately sharing the same controller.

I thought I could do it by calling something like `params[:foo] == "bar"` , but at this point in the series of methods, there are no params available. That is because it is a method called before create.

```
create.before :create_before
```

However! They would have different URL's! So if I can just find a way to pull the params of the current url, I can solve this problem.

Any takers?

This is Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're actually in the controller, you can call `request.path`, which will return the currently requested path. However, given that `params` is not available, you may not actually be in a controller at that point. You have any code you can share?

Comment: i ended up cleaning up my filthy code and being a good programmer. fixed my problem. thanks for the help